# IE (html table) issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

What's wrong?

```
<table id="PollDetails" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                Poll Question:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" runat="server" id="lblSelection1" visible="true">
                Selection    1:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelection1" runat="server" Width="300" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" runat="server" id="lblSelection2" visible="true">
                Selection 2:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelection2" runat="server" Width="300" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" runat="server" id="lblSelection3" visible="true">
                Selection 3:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelection3" runat="server" Width="300" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" runat="server" id="lblSelection4" visible="true">
                Selection 4:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelection4" runat="server" Width="300" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" runat="server" id="lblSelection5" visible="true">
                Selection 5:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelection5" runat="server" Width="300" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CausesValidation="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Generated Code pasted:

```
<div>
<table id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_PollDetails">
<tr>
        <td align="right">
                Poll Question:
           </td>
        <td align="left">
               <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtQuestion" type="text"     value="How much time do you spend on a computer daily?" id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtQuestion" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_lblSelection1" align="right">Selection 1:
        </td>
    <td align="left">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtSelection1" type="text" value="Less than 1 Hour" id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtSelection1" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_lblSelection2" align="right">Selection 2:

        </td>
    <td align="left">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtSelection2" type="text" value="Between 1 and 2 Hours " id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtSelection2" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_lblSelection3" align="right">Selection 3:

        </td>
    <td align="left">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtSelection3" type="text" value="Between 2 and 4 Hours " id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtSelection3" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_lblSelection4" align="right">Selection 4:

        </td>
    <td align="left">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtSelection4" type="text" value="Between 4 and 8 Hours " id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtSelection4" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_lblSelection5" align="right">Selection 5:

        </td>
    <td align="left">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$txtSelection5" type="text" value="Between 8 and 16 Hours" id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_txtSelection5" style="width:300px;" />
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        </td>
    <td>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$btnSave" value="Save Changes" id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_btnSave" />
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPage$PollManagement$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_ContentPage_PollManagement_btnCancel" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the entire table HTML code.  My guess is the table isn't well-formed and the browsers are interpreting it differently (i.e. not all tags have matching ending tags.)

Comment: Do you have a place where the entire source and css can be seen?

Comment: The code you've pasted there checks out OK - please post the actual HTML that's generated

Comment: At the bottom you have an empty td, did you mean to place one of the buttons in there?

Comment: The image is now dead, making the question less clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table, as posted, shows up properly on the IE7 so it has to be because of surrounding HTML markup in your page.

Comment: You gave me a big hint. I will post my progress

Comment: The problem was being caused by a div. Changed the div poistion and now ok. Thanks for you suggestions

Answer (score 1):

What DOCTYPE are you using? IE could be interpreting the page differently than Firefox depending on your DOCTYPE.

If you're unfamiliar with DOCTYPES, [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) has a good description of them.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all of the [visible ="false"] and completing the closing table table tag delivers the desired output.  Start from there.

Answer (score 0):

What is visible and what is not?
Changing all your visibile=false to true it looks fine in ie7.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting a & nbsp; inside the blank TD tag near the bottom.

Comment: missing a non-breaking space isn't the culprit.